# AWS AMI Linux set crontab using arguments. I tried many solutions but can't resolve

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I need to set one crone job with passing arguments using crontab of AWS AMI Linux.

I was tried like many things but none of working,

```
0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php command=purge-unused-uploaded-files

0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php?command=purge-unused-uploaded-files

0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php command="purge-unused-uploaded-files"

0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php -args command=purge-unused-uploaded-files

0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php -args command="purge-unused-uploaded-files"
```

Please help me!

Comment: Could you please give more detail ?

Comment: @MuhammetArslan - I want to setup cron job with argument, as above listed tried all that way but i can not get argument(command) in script so my specific code not running.

Answer (score 0):

do you use $_GET in the script? Its not set when run like you do. Add this code

```
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
```

to parse the command line args into $_GET. Or use curl.

Comment: No, I am not using $_GET in script. I am using $_REQUEST.

Comment: parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_REQUEST);